# Searching top keys based on values of nested dicts on python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

There are many questions that cover similars concets, but not this especifically.
I use nested dicts, two levels, all values are unique and need to find the root key based on a value inside a child dict.
I have a code, but it feels not optimal. Care to help?

Exemple dict:

```
maindict = {"First Node"  : {0: "00", 1: "01", 2: "02", 3: "03"},
        "Second Node" : {0: "10", 1: "11", 2: "12", 3: "13"},
        "Third Node"  : {0: "20", 1: "21", 2: "22", 3: "33"}}

def search_root(val):
    for i, dict in enumerate(list(maindict.values())):
        if val in list(dict.values()):
            return list(maindict.keys())[i]
```

I feel like this for loop and if statement could be simplyfied somehow but I don't have the knowledge to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can escape a loop in this case in any reasonable way, but you can make things clearer and (maybe) avoid some conversions,

```
def find_root(target_val, maindict):
    for key, val in maindict.items():
        if target_val in maindict[key].values():
            return key

maindict = {"First Node"  : {0: "00", 1: "01", 2: "02", 3: "03"},
        "Second Node" : {0: "10", 1: "11", 2: "12", 3: "13"},
        "Third Node"  : {0: "20", 2: "11", 2: "22", 3: "23"}}

target_val = "22"

target_node = find_root(target_val, maindict)
```

The above takes advantage of dictionary-specific functionality. Also, avoid calling variables `dict`, `list` etc. since those are Python builtin names for those data structures.

Comment: Will test it and see the difference in speed mainly.
But I agree that I shouldn't name variables by reserved words, that was my tired mind.

Comment: your is much, MUCH, faster. 
829 ns ± 3.81 ns per loop. vs mine 1.41 µs ± 79.5 ns per loop

Comment: Nice! I wasn't sure since I didn't benchmark it myself, but I suspected it may be faster since it fetches things in bulk and possibly uses some leaner mechanisms to work on them. Good to know.